# Overriding Codeigniter routing with .htaccess

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-routing, .htaccess

Is it possible to mask a URL (**not redirect**) in Codeigniter using a RewriteRule in htaccess **rather than** using routing inside routes.php?

My goal is to achieve the following:

URL visible to the user --> **https://example.com/search/query/page**

Actual URL --> **https://example.com/search?q=query&p=page**

What I've tried so far, with no luck:

In routes.php --> **$route["search/(:any)/(:any)"] = "search?q=$1&p=$2";**

In .htaccess --> **RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)$ /search?q=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]**

I've actually considered migrating the whole application from query strings to URL segments, but unfortunately I'm bound to working with an existing codebase from a client and migrating isn't really an option.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

try this route:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure my problem can't be solved in routes.php, because the routes don't accept query strings. I'm certain that the htaccess rule I wrote is good, it's just not working with CodeIgniter

Comment: i have updated  answer try  this htaccess.i am using too.i hope it will help you.

Comment: The purpose of that is to remove the index.php from the URL, and I'm already using it, but it has no connection with my query string problem specifically. Thanks anyway! :)